# Android : Upgrading to target version 27 sdk

Tags: android, libraries

I want to upgrade my project to api level **27** from api level 25. I used plenty of third party library like RxJava, Exoplayer , dagger etc. 
RxJava version used in my project is **1.x.x** not **2.x.x**. So I have following questions

1. If I am upgrading gradle with current api level, whether other third party library need to be upgraded to target api level 27 ?
2. If yes. there are several library which still using 24 or 23 targete api and no update available so for. Is there is any issue using this ?
3. Meet Google Play's target API level requirement document say all apk from November need to target api level 26 [details](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk). So this applies to third party library too ? 
   Suppose I am using some image crop library having targeted version 23. In that case will my apk get rejected from google play store ?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. If I am upgrading gradle with current api level, whether other third
>      party library need to be upgraded to target api level 27 ?

I don't think you'll need to ***upgrade*** those third-parties libraries because it's out of your hands I'd say and that's all depends on the developer. But, ***it should work fine i suppose***. Also, you may wanna consider using the latest version for libraries when updated the `API` to 27.

> 2. If yes. there are several library which still using 24 or 23 targete
>      api and no update available so for. Is there is any issue using this
>      ?

It might just cause some issues(**not working, not compatible or ...**) because of new API on Android itself(*behavior or etc*) using newer versions but, there will be new updates of course and mostly, most of them works in my side.

> 3. Meet Google Play's target API level requirement document say all apk
>      from November need to target api level 26 details. So this applies to
>      third party library too ? Suppose I am using some image crop library
>      having targeted version 23. In that case will my apk get rejected from
>      google play store ?

The answer to this question is "Perhaps". I mean, if they said it should be at least supporting `v26 APIs`, so, some libraries might not work (***Depreciated codes-methods***)on the new APIs and might Google recognize that and your app won't be accepted so, you may wanna update as they just said and reconsidering targeted APIs with libraries which supports the targeted `API +`.

Comment: The image cropper library doesn't have any new releases at all. They have stopped after API 23 only. Does this mean my application can be rejected?

Comment: That actually depends on the methods-codes which developer used to create the library which you should consider checking on the **new APIs** and if it worked (*which probably will i hope*), then we can hope they will accept it.